# Tabular with matrix inside

Tags: tables, matrices

[image]

Help anyone! I tried an I tried so I try my luck hopefully there someone out there with sharper tabular and matrix skills.

Comment: Welcome. Please, show us what you tried and tried. You can edit your post and insert a minimal piece of code so we can help you to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since virtually all of the material in the table is math-y, I recommend you use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. That way, you'll 
need to type `$` only twice -- before `\begin{array}` and after `\end{array}`-- instead of at the start and end of the 33 [!] cells that contain math-mode material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\newcommand{\smbullet}{{\scriptscriptstyle\bullet}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
$\begin{array}{|c|cccc|c|}
\hline
\text{Material\textbackslash Klass} & B_1 & B_2 & \dots & B_k & \text{Summa}\\
\hline
1 & o_{11} & o_{12} & \dots & o_{1k} & n_1=o_{1\smbullet} \\
2 & o_{21} & o_{22} & \dots & o_{2k} & n_2=o_{2\smbullet} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots & \vdots\\
r & o_{r1} & o_{r2} & \dots & o_{rk} & n_r=o_{r\smbullet} \\
\hline
\text{Sammanlagt} & o_{\smbullet1} & o_{\smbullet2} & \dots & o_{\smbullet k} & n_\smbullet \\
\hline
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: array>tabular  
smbullet>bullet
|c|cccc|c|>|c|c|c|c|c|c|

thank you again Mico